# Проблема с подключением SASS

Tags: sass

После загрузки модуля SASS в командной строке выдало следующее 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как в дальнейшем влияет на работоспособность, но при запуске команды
gulp-sass выдает следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что написано в моем файле main.sass

```html
body 
background-color: #ff0
```

Таким образом, не могу понять, в чем проблема.
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуй сделать отступ табом:

```
body 
 background-color: #ff0
```

Comment: да, все верно, спасибо ;)

Comment: @Miroslav если ответ помог, то отмечайте его решением.

Comment: Ну я отступ 2 пробелами сделал